# Run your Linux (graphics) completely on Nvidia dedicated graphics card?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia, graphics, desktop-environment

I'm running an Arch and I've had a hard time for some months trying to figure out how to run my [Optimus Laptop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus) completely on Nvidia dedicated GPU. How do I do this? I've heard there are multiple options out there but I don't know how to pull it off! So how do I get to enjoy my powerful **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile** on Linux?

##### Any ideas or setups that might help me to run any GPU-related task on my Nvidia GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem for some time till I discovered a utility to do it all. You can use the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus) to see how an Optimus Laptop works.
And then you have multiple options, but I suggest running the [optimus-manager](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager#optimus-manager) if you are using external screens as well, and you want to use the intel graphics while on battery power.

This is the output that `optimus-manager --status`should give if you're running completely on the NVIDIA card:

```
optimus-manager --status
Optimus Manager (Client) version 1.4

Current GPU mode : nvidia
GPU mode requested for next login : no change
GPU at startup : nvidia
Temporary config path: no
```

Carefully follow the [Installation Wiki](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager#installation) for your Arch Linux Desktop Environment and be sure to check the [FAQ](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager/wiki/FAQ,-common-issues,-troubleshooting#faq) before you make the switch and could end up in the `tty` not knowing what to do.

##### Update: this setup will work on both X11 and Wayland (using KDE Plasma now).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is an alternative solution to the above: It's a good solution if you have an Optimus laptop and you're not using any external monitors, but you want to use nvidia all the time.

For a long time now I have used `optimus-manager` to run my graphics through the Nvidia GPU, but because it's dynamic it has proven to have issues here and there sometimes. When I needed to just get things done with my machine, I ran into a black screen, or something wasn't working and I had to go and troubleshoot the issues.

Therefore for anyone that wants a stable & static solution that will work 99% of the time this is it: [Use NVIDIA graphics only](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only) .

Follow the steps in there and you're good to go all the time, hopefully.

**Note:** Compared to the above this method will not allow you to switch to the integrated GPU, but will always run your graphics through the nvidia GPU.